# Source not found in debugging mode

Tags: java, sql

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DBTesting {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try 
        {
            String user = "sa";
            String pass = "xxx";


            String jdbcURL = "jdbc:odbc:btrsDSN";
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            System.out.println("Driver Loaded !");

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL,user,pass);
            System.out.println("Connection Obtained");

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();


            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Error occurs in this line when the debugger tries to debug the 
`Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL,user,pass);` . It shows source not found. I edit source lookup path but the problem still here. I also try many solutions from internet but none of them solve the problem. For convenience I also attached screen shots.

[Snapshot in regular mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRDsM.jpg)

[Snapshot in Debugging mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCLIf.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

click on "edit source Lookup path" and specify the path where that particular file exists, then you will be available to see the java lines of code.

if the java file is in different project and your current project is accessing the class through jar file ,then configure your current project to work with "project dependency" instead of "jar dependency"

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Dear Vihar,  Thanks for your response. It also show this error  'Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:btrsDSN
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at DBTesting.main(DBTesting.java:21)'

Comment: I think you are using sqlServer so have a look at this example and do accordingly https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342339(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".